# How can I merge a Tag on my branch?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I'm working with only a master branch, just like this:

BRANCH (Remote repo)
A --> B --> C ( --> D --> E )

User1 starting from A does two commit B and C (local commit, tag, e push to remote)

User2 starting from A does two commit D and E (only local commit and tag)

User2 did a fetch but all was updated (I'm still wondering why), but under Repository TAG appeared B and C. Then User2 tries to merge C with master branch, but an error has occurred (we're using Egit plugin in Eclipse).

User2 push his changes to remote repo, but nothing change.

Anyway, there's a way to join C and E changes and commit in one version?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the error message from EGit? Either it should be in the error dialog or in the *Error Log* view.

Answer (score 0):

`git checkout E && git merge C` should do the trick. You'll end up with commit `F` as a result of the merge operation.

Comment: I've already tried: but the result is: An error occurred Merging with refs/tags/V1.06. The target is just create F as a result of merge.

Comment: What's the exact error message? What happens if you try `git checkout E && git cherry-pick C`? Internal errors in Git aren't easy to recover from...

Comment: I'm working with EGIT in Eclipse and I don't use git command, maybe a plugin bug?

Comment: Not necessarily. If I were you, I'd try to fix this by hand first: 1. find the repository on your disk and make a copy. 2. Run the git commands on the copy from the command line. If that works then the problem might be with EGIT, otherwise EGIT will not be able to help you anyway.